# Aplicar CSS conforme URL

Tags: jquery, css

Quando eu estiver no /inicio o CSS  **header nav ul li .submenu** deve ser *top:300px*, nas demais páginas deve ser *top:120px*.
Coloquei dentro do **$(document).ready(function() { });** a seguinte expressão:

```
$("a[href='/inicio]").find("header nav ul li .submenu").css("top", "300px!important");
```

Mas não está funcionando.
O CSS está assim:

```
header nav ul li .submenu {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffae11;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    font-size: 0;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

Comment: Não precisa daquele important, o important é utilizado apenas quando o DOM está sendo carregado. o jquery vai mudar de qualquer forma. Isso não resolve o problema eu sei, mas ja é um incio

Comment: Obrigado, vou tirar.

Comment: Aliás talvez possa até resolver, tendo em vista que o !important estava colocado de forma errada e poderia estar atrapalhando a instrução

Comment: Tirei o *!important* mas ainda não está funcionando.

Comment: De uma olhada na minha resposta, você possuí outros estilo no .submenu? dentro de outros elementos ou existe apenas um estilo para a `.submenu`?

Comment: Se você quer que mude o css em uma única página é bem mais fácil colocar um id lá e no css mudar pelo id deichando o código do id depois do normal para não ser sobre escrito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, vamos tentar resolver de uma forma fácil ok?

acredito eu que este **/inicio** seja a página principal do seu site correto?

Então você criou uma instrução que detecta se é ou não a página principal através do link. Vamos dar uma alterada nisso? Vamos la.

Para detectarmos se é ou não a página principal você pode adicionar na tag `<body>` de sua página essa informação! Segue o exemplo.

**no HTML adicione:**

```
<body class='principal'>
```

*eu particularmente prefiro trabalhar utilizando classes*

Pois bem, agora no Jquery vamos fazer uma função que procure a informação presente no body. Veja:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   if($('body').hasClass('principal')) 
   {
      $("header nav ul li .submenu").css("top", "300px");
   }

});
```